# How can one execute ROP attack in presence of zero addresses in stack and overwrite RBP and RIP registers?

Tags: windows, stack, buffer, overflow, 64-bit

**How to overwrite the RBP and RIP register on the stack for a ROP (Return-oriented programming) attack if I have addresses in the stack begin and end with \x000000.......?**

I'm practicing buffer overflow attack on a Windows 10 64-bit machine. However, I have found that the addresses in the stack begin and end with addresses \x000000....... which is making it difficult for me to exploit since I cannot use the ROP (Return-oriented programming) technique. I am able to overwrite the RBP register, but when I want to overwrite the RIP register it is impossible since the address in the RBP register contains zeros so it does not copy all the contents of the buffer to the stack. I attach an image of what is described.

Is there a way to bypass such that I can overwrite the RBP register address and RIP register on the stack when it contains zeros to execute a ROP attack or any recommendations I can follow?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp8jk.png)

Overwrite the $RBP and $RIP registers to continue the ROP technique

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.